# subscribe angular2 not working

Tags: angular, angular2-services, subscribe

I must be missing something very obvious, but I'm having problems using subscribe on a component to listen a change in a service.

I have a login component(not posted here) which calls the login method in the LoginService, the navbar component should listen when a user login.

What am I missing?

My Service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private request = new Request();
    private sessionData:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([])
    public session:Observable<any>

    constructor(private http: Http, _router: Router) {
        console.log("Login Service created.", http);
        this.session = this.sessionData.asObservable()
    }

    public getSessionData(): Observable<any>{
        return this.sessionData.asObservable();
    }

    login(userCredentials:UserCredentials):Observable<any> {    
        console.log("requesting login")
        this.request.ServiceType = "Connect"
        this.request.SessionId = "sessionlessrequest"
        this.request.Compression = "no"
        this.request.Parameters = userCredentials;
        let jsonrequest = JSON.stringify(this.request)
        return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonrequest,
            { headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })
        }).map( (responseData) => {
            this.sessionData = responseData.json();
            this.sessionData.next;
            this.sessionData.share;
            this.session = responseData.json();
            console.log(this.sessionData)
            return null
        })
    }
```

Then there is my component:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './app/navbar/navbar.component.html',
    providers: [SessionService, LoginService, UserCredentials]
})

export class NavBarComponent {
    sessionData: any
    constructor(sessionService: SessionService, private loginService: LoginService, private userCredentials: UserCredentials) {
    }

    ngOninit() {
        this.loginService.getSessionData().subscribe((value => {
            this.sessionData = value;
            console.log(this.sessionData)
        }))
    }
```

Gunter thank you for your help

**Update after Günter's answer:**

app.module.ts

```ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        LoginComponent,

    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        routing,

    ],
    providers: [appRoutingProviders, LoginService ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

LoginComponent.ts:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: './app/login/login.component.html',
    providers: []
})

    export class LoginComponent {
        public usercredentials = new UserCredentials();
        constructor(private loginService:LoginService) {

        }
        login() {
            console.log(this.usercredentials)
            this.loginService.login(this.usercredentials).subscribe()
        }
    }
```

LoginService.ts:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private request = new Request();
    private sessionData:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([])
    public session:Observable<any>
    constructor(private http: Http, _router: Router) {
        console.log("Login Service created.", http);
        this.session = this.sessionData.asObservable()
    }

    public getSessionData(): Observable<any>{
        return this.sessionData.asObservable();
    }

    login(userCredentials:UserCredentials):Observable<any> {    
        console.log("requesting login")
        this.request.ServiceType = "Connect"
        this.request.SessionId = "sessionlessrequest"
        this.request.Compression = "no"
        this.request.Parameters = userCredentials;
        let jsonrequest = JSON.stringify(this.request)
        return this.http.post("http://localhost/request.php", "data="+ jsonrequest,
            { headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })
        }).map( (responseData) => {
            this.sessionData = responseData.json();
            this.sessionData.next;
            this.sessionData.share;
            this.session = responseData.json();
            console.log(this.sessionData)
            return null
        })
}
```

navbar component.ts :

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './app/navbar/navbar.component.html',
    providers: []
})

export class NavBarComponent {
    sessionData: any
    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {

    }

    ngOninit() {
        this.loginService.getSessionData().subscribe((value => {
            this.sessionData = value;
            console.log(this.sessionData)
        }))
    }
```

I see in my debugger that I get only 1 instance of loginservice, however it still doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to share a service with other components or services in your application, don't provide it everywhere where you use it.

Where you want to use it you add it as constructor parameter.

To define where a single instance should be shared in your application, decide where to put it as provider. Angular2 DI maintains a single instance per provider.

If you add `SessionService`, `LoginService`, and `UserCredentials` on every component, every component will get a different instance. 
When you add it to `@NgModule()` then one instance will be shared with your entire application:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [SessionService, LoginService, UserCredentials]
})
class AppModule {}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: './app/navbar/navbar.component.html',
    providers: []
})
```

**update**

`this.sessionData.next;` doesn't do anything. It should be `this.sessionData.next(someValue)`.

Also `this.sessionData.share;` should be `this.session = this.sessionData.asObservable().share()`

Comment: Did I understand correctly from your 1st comments, that if you have a service that is only used by one component, you should use the provider in the component?

Comment: Where you provide it determines where a specific instance will be shared. If you provide it at a component only this component or  it's children will be able to inject it. If this is desired, then provide it at the component. If it should be global for your application, then share it in NgModule

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense. Really appreciate it